# CasperJS has been redirected and then exited with status=fail (HTTP 302)

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, centos, phantomjs, casperjs

CasperJS version 1.1.4 at /opt/casperjs, using phantomjs version 2.1.1. Running on centOS.

Trying to get through authentication page which runs on ASP.net webforms, but after submit button click:

```
casper.then(function(){
if (this.exists("#LoginTyreLink_LoginButton")) {
    this.echo("Login button found");
    this.click("#LoginTyreLink_LoginButton", function(){
        saveShot("login_button_clicked");
    });
}
});
```

I am getting the redirect cycle and timeout:

```
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mouseup' on selector: #Loginsite_LoginButton
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: #Loginsite_LoginButton
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 14/17: done in 3131ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 15/17 https://site.brand.eu/link/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 15/17: done in 3155ms.
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://site.brand.eu/link/Homepage.aspx, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://site.brand.eu/link/Login.aspx, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://site.brand.eu/link//Homepage.aspx, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://site.brand.eu/link/Login.aspx, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://site.brand.eu/link/Homepage.aspx, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://site.brand.eu/link/Login.aspx, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://site.brand.eu/link/Homepage.aspx, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://site.brand.eu/link/Login.aspx, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://site.brand.eu/link/Homepage.aspx, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://site.brand.eu/link/Login.aspx, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail (HTTP 302): https://site.brand.eu/link/Login.aspx
[debug] [phantom] Automatically injected includes/jquery-3.3.1.js client side
[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout
[error] [phantom] Wait timeout of 20000ms expired, exiting.
Wait timeout of 20000ms expired, exiting.
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"
```

I've tried to run the script on my local machine - it succeded, but can not on my remote centOS machine.

P.S.

It was fine for over a year...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned above - the platform is centOS.
It's hilarious but...

```
sudo yum update
```

Then:

```
sudo reboot
```

Mission accomplished.